# Fstab - mount a folder that has mounted folders in it

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab, ftp

I have an ftp server where I am binding all of the home directories to a folder that has folders in it which were bound to other hard drives.

[Anime hard disk] -> mounted to ftp/Anime/

[ftp] -> mounted to kevin/

I want all of the folders inside the ftp folder to show up in all of the users directories with all of its contents. Currently it will show the folders with nothing in it. Could it be a permissions problem?

Here is my fstab:

```
UUID=90f5fb7f-225f-4c4c-8564-b3c2f16f683d /media/Disk1 ext4 defaults auto nofail, 0 4 #Games
UUID=34a6f835-8ec3-4feb-994d-be669a5ed6cf /media/Disk2 ext4 defaults auto nofail, 0 4 #Video
UUID=f2d0ad61-3a36-4220-9f15-0e11fc4caedc /media/Disk3 ext4 defaults auto nofail, 0 4
UUID=c794c506-9057-4331-8044-d07df5505f03 /media/Disk4 ext4 defaults auto nofail, 0 4

#Mounts for FTP
/media/Disk2/Video /home/vftp/ftp/Movies/ none bind 0 4
/media/Disk4/Anime /home/vftp/ftp/Anime/ none bind 0 4
/media/Disk4/CartoonSeries/ /home/vftp/ftp/Cartoons/ none bind 0 4
/media/Disk3/Programs /home/vftp/ftp/Applications/ none bind 0 4
/media/Disk1/ /home/vftp/ftp/Games/ none bind 0 4
/media/Disk3/Music/ /home/vftp/ftp/Music/ none bind 0 4
/media/Disk3/Books/ /home/vftp/ftp/Books/ none bind 0 4
/media/Disk3/StudyMaterial/ /home/vftp/ftp/StudyMaterial/ none bind 0 4

/home/vftp/ftp/ /home/vftp/kevin/ none bind 0 4
```

EDIT:

So apparently one can use the rbind option. I just don't know if its possible  in the fstab. I added the option to the fstab in the hopes that it would bind everything recursively. It didn't, so I appended `mount -a` (to remount all entries in the fstab) to the /etc/rc.local script and it worked. Can anyone explain why it refuses to do this in the fstab? or can anyone show how it can be done without having to do a `mount -a`?

```
/home/vftp/ftp/ /home/vftp/kevin/ none rbind 0 0
```

Further reading: https://docs.1h.com/Bind_mounts

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do this you can mount hdd drive to another, and then alter the fstab to mount the directory to the hdd whit this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/media/disk2/Video  /home/vftp/ftp/Movies/  nodev,noexec,nosuid       1
/media/disk4/Anime  /home/vftp/ftp/Anime/   nodev,noexec,nosuid       1
/media/Disk4/CartoonSeries/ /home/vftp/ftp/Cartoons/ nodev,noexec,nosuid 1
/media/Disk3/Programs /home/vftp/ftp/Applications/ nodev,noexec,nosuid 1
/media/Disk1/ /home/vftp/ftp/Games/ nodev,noexec,nosuid 1
/media/Disk3/Music/ /home/vftp/ftp/Music/ nodev,noexec,nosuid 1
/media/Disk3/Books/ /home/vftp/ftp/Books/ nodev,noexec,nosuid 1
/media/Disk3/StudyMaterial/ /home/vftp/ftp/StudyMaterial/ nodev,noexec,nosuid 1
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=90f5fb7f-225f-4c4c-8564-b3c2f16f683d /media/Disk1   ext4  error=remount-ro        1
UUID=34a6f835-8ec3-4feb-994d-be669a5ed6cf /media/Disk2   ext4  error=remount-ro        1
UUID=34a6f835-8ec3-4feb-994d-be669a5ed6cf /media/Disk3   ext4  error=remount-ro        1
UUID=f2d0ad61-3a36-4220-9f15-0e11fc4caedc /media/Disk4   ext4  error=remount-ro        1
/home/vftp/ftp/ /home/vftp/kevin/ /media/Disk1   1
/home/vftp/ftp/ /home/vftp/kevin/ /media/Disk2   1
/home/vftp/ftp/ /home/vftp/kevin/ /media/Disk3   1
/home/vftp/ftp/ /home/vftp/kevin/ /media/Disk4   1
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: didnt seem to work.

Comment: tried doing a mount --bind /home/vftp/ftp/ /home/vftp/kevin/ and it did the same as my fstab. but then tried using the -rbind and it worked. Now to do this in the fstab

Comment: I found some information about mounting points that have the same structure "Note that when you mount a filesystem somewhere else, any filesystems that were mounted to mount points inside the bind-mounted filesystem will not be moved along."